# Is it possible to customize a CPToolbar in Cappuccino

Tags: cappuccino

I may need to change toolbar background, heading font and position.
Is it possible to do that with the standard CPToolbar? I was looking through the ThemeDescriptors.j, and there is nothing about a Toolbar.

It seams not so difficult to create my own. Should I go that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toolbar isn't themeable as is (although, feel free to implement that for us. :) )

That said, you could do something like this depending on what exactly you want to do…
https://github.com/cappuccino/issues/blob/master/Client/AppController.j#L273